# JSCS error: X and Y should have at most 2 line(s) between them at

Tags: javascript, jscs

> ; and $rootScope should have at most 2 line(s) between them at app/scripts/services/betslipfactory.js :
>
> ```
>   131 |            }
>    132 |            $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
>    133 |          });
> ---------------------^
>    134 |
>    135 |
> ```
>
> 1 code style errors found!

that is the error I am getting here

```
_.each(status.selections, function(selection) {
            $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="well">';
            $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>' + selection.teamName  + ' </strong>';
            if (selection.lineChange) {
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="row">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="col-md-12">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>Lines:</strong>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="row">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="col-md-6">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>Before</strong>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div>' + selection.oldSpread + '(' + selection.oldMoneyLine + ')';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="col-md-6">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>Current</strong>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div>' + selection.newSpread + '(' + selection.newMoneyLine + ')';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
            }

            if (selection.timeChange) {
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="row">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="col-md-6">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>Previous Time:</strong>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div>' + selection.oldDate + '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="col-md-6">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>Current Time:</strong>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div>' + selection.newDate + '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
            }

            if (selection.statusChange) {
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="row">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="col-md-6">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>Old Status:</strong>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div>' + selection.oldStatus + '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="col-md-6">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>New Status:</strong>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div>' + selection.newStatus + '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
            }

            if (selection.pitchingChangeThis) {
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="row">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="col-md-12">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>New Pitcher On Your Team:</strong>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div>' + selection.newPlayerNameThis + '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
            }

            if (selection.pitchingChangeOther) {
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="row">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div class="col-md-12">';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<strong>New Pitcher On The Other Team:</strong>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '<div>' + selection.newPlayerNameOther + '</div>';
              $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>';
            }
            $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>'; //closing the '<div .well>' tag...       
          });
             //HERE IS THE ERROR ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you probably have 2 blank lines between:

```
  $rootScope.copyLineStatus += '</div>'; //closing the '<div .well>' tag...       
});
```

and the next line of code.

---

### Auto fixing code

#### With JSCS only

In the console run:

```
jscs "myfile.js" --fix
```

You can also point it to a directory or a list of files. Check the [documentation for more info](http://jscs.info/overview.html)

#### In Sublime

There's a puglin called [**SublimeJSCSFormatter**](https://github.com/TheSavior/SublimeJSCSFormatter) that should do that for you. Never used it though.

#### WebStorm/PHPStorm

Just press `CTRL+ALT+L` or `CMD+ALT+L` (in mac)

Comment: yes, actually were 2 blank lines that will never notice if you don't start going line by line watching and deleting every blank line. Is there a way to set up Sublime to remove that kind of lines ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a little aside from what the OP was after but may serve others that look for this error:

If you want to be able to have multiple line breaks to space out your code for a bit more readability, you can remove this line from your *.jscsrc* file. Note that you cannot set this to false as it's either true or needs to be removed.

```
"disallowMultipleLineBreaks": true
```

While this gives you more flexibility, that also means you may need to apply a common approach across your development team to stay consistent.